# date filter using elasticsearch, using nest c#

Tags: c#, datetime, elasticsearch, nest

I am having mapping for a date field like shown below.

```
.Date(s => s.Name("createdOn").Format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS||yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss||MM/dd/yyyy||yyyy/MM/dd"))
```

I want to get documents created after a certain date. I am passing date as string in the format MM/dd/yyyy to the filter range like shown below..

```
DateTime date;
DateTime.TryParse(filter.SearchText, out date);
string dateString = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
query = filterDesc.And(filterDesc.Range(n =>n.Greater(dateString).OnField(searchFields[filter.Field])));
```

But elastic search is considering time also in the search. i.e i want to get documents created after `2/10/2015`, I am getting documents which are created on `2/10/2015` also. Please let me know the possible solution.

Thanks and in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you want to search for documents created on or after "2/11/2015 00:00". The code below should work I guess; I did not try it myself though.

```
DateTime date;
DateTime.TryParse(filter.SearchText, out date);
date = date.Date.AddDays(1); // date = floor(date) + 1 day
string dateString = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
query = filterDesc.And(filterDesc.Range(n =>n.GreaterOrEquals(dateString).OnField(searchFields[filter.Field])));
```

Mind you, if date in a document actually is exactly "2/10/2015 00:00", the document will not be returned as part of results of the above query. This is because we convert the date to "2/11/2015 00:00". But if you do not want this behaviour, you can tweak my solution as per your requirements.

Comment: In NEST 1.4.1 at least, the date related range methods have an overload for format, like `n.GreaterOrEquals(date, "MM/dd/yyyy")`. Just to help keep things a little cleaner.

Comment: @Snixtor I've done exactly that if you notice. The minor complexity in date computation is for meeting the requirements of the question asked.

Comment: @bsarkar I am looking for documents created after '2/11/2015'. I tried the overload method with format. But still no luck. As a temporary fix by setting the date as '2/11/2015 23:59:59' I am getting the required documents.

Comment: @RavindraKumarChallagandla I think there is some confusion here. My code works fine if you want to search for documents created after `2/10/2015` as that is what you asked for in your question. If it works for you, then please mark it as answer.

Comment: @baskar I don't want to include timestamp while searching for documents. Is there any way I can achieve this ?

Comment: @RavindraKumarChallagandla Isn't that then just a question of your own implementation choice? If a stored date is 2015-02-12 4:15:22, is 2015-02-12 greater than, or equal to it? You may need to manipulate the filter date accordingly (as bsarkar has shown), and make careful choice in your use of the `Greater` or `GreaterOrEquals` filter type.